# Not able to convert Excel file to CSV

Tags: excel, excel-2010, export-to-csv

I have an Excel file with 2 sheets. One with my data with headers and the other is for references. It's basically a template where I am using Sheet 2 for reference values. When I save the file to CSV, it saves all garbage data which I think are due to 2 work sheets and the references between them.

Please find the attached [excel sheet](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=5E64BB06AF7A6627!527&authkey=!AOmlFm3SUgkLfdA&ithint=file%2cxlsx) and let me know how I can do a proper conversion?

Notes:

1. I am using Office 2010 Standard
2. I have tried copying and pasting with "Values" option.
3. I have tried copying and pasting with "Merge Destination Formatting"

Nothing worked.

Comment: I have a solution for this but I don't consider it to be generic so I ignored it. I have to copy the records in my Excel, go to Run Program and put excel and hit enter. This opens the new excel file. (Note that, clicking new from Menu is a different thing) Now, use Paste with option Merge Destination Formatting. Close the original excel file, remove the other 2 sheets which are default and empty in this new excel file. Save it as CSV. This works. But as I said, its not generic.

Comment: What extension has file you are working on? Does it have more than 1 sheet?

Comment: The extension is .xls and yes it has 2 sheets. I have attached the file. You can check the link.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the solution.

When you copy the selected range of records and paste them to New excel file, just drag the cursor some columns ahead. Remove the newly added columns (Not sure from where they come). Now do a Save As CSV. Thats it.